# how to send erc20 tokens using Web3js

Tags: javascript, web3js

I am trying to send erc20 token using web3js version 1.6.1 but I cant understand why it is not working

I am using  [this](https://piyopiyo.medium.com/how-to-send-erc20-token-with-web3-js-1-0-0-95164b32e9a6) article and did all the steps exactly

i am using walletconnect/web3-provider as the provider

i can transfer ETH successfully but for the tokens it seems I am missing some thing that i cant find out what it is.

**this is my code**

```
async sendToken() {
      let address = "0x0d8775f648430679a709e98d2b0cb6250d2887ef"; // BAT Token Contract Address
      let minABI = [
        {
          "constant": false,
          "inputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "address",
              "name": "recipient",
              "type": "address"
            },
            {
              "internalType": "uint256",
              "name": "amount",
              "type": "uint256"
            }
          ],
          "name": "transfer",
          "outputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "bool",
              "name": "",
              "type": "bool"
            }
          ],
          "payable": false,
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "function"
        },

      ];
      let contract =new this.web3.eth.Contract(minABI,address);
      let decimals = this.web3.utils.toBN(18);
      let amount = this.web3.utils.toBN(10);
      let value = amount.mul(this.web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(decimals));
      let toAddress="toAddress";
      contract.methods.transfer(toAddress, value).send({from: this.account})
          .on('transactionHash', function(hash){
            console.log(hash);
          })
    }
```

this is screen shot from my trust wallet but I cant not get the expected result

[screen shot of smart contract call in trust wallet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NthJ.jpg)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Andreas thanks I edited my post and add some more details :}